# Avoiding texture switching (openGL es 2.0)

Tags: ios, opengl-es, rendering, glsl

I'm working on small 2d rendering engine for IOS. I want to render many sprites that are located in different textures. Now that sounds simple... Just render all sprites that belong to same texture and move to next ... But how to handle overlapping of primitives that have different textures?

[image: problem]

I want to render them in exact same way as on the picture (overlapped). That means I need to switch texture three times. What if I have hundreeds of such mixed sprites? To avoid texture switching on client and render all sprites in one shot. I'm using following code in fragment shader:

```
if(txt >= 0.5)
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(texture1, texCoords)* clr;

if (txt >= 1.5)
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(texture2, texCoords)* clr;

if (txt >= 2.5)
    gl_FragColor= texture2D(texture3, texCoords)* clr;

if (txt >= 3.5)
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(texture4, texCoords)* clr;

if (txt >= 4.5)
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(texture5, texCoords) * clr;
```

Because of dynamic branching I have performance issues running on device. Is there better solution?

Comment: You never get your app to scale if your going to have lots of texture and vertext. You need to be using VBOs and FBOs, then switching bettween texture is setting a new pointer.

Comment: A common way to combat this is to make use of a texture atlas -> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texture_atlas

Comment: @Pareshkumar Let's say I have two elements A and B in  VBO-A and VBO-B both VBO's assigned to different textures. Let's say I need to render first A and then on top B, then again A and then B. I need to make 4 switches, is this correct?

Comment: @borrrden I'm already using multiple texture atlases. Let say you developing UI library and you have font(s) atlas and elements atlas. Now you need to render text over element and then overlap it with different element (popup) with another text. We got exactly same problem even with texture atlases (in current case two). I mean you can't keep everything in single texture atlas as maximum dimentions is 2048 x 2048

Comment: changing a Buffer ID on the GL stack is a different story then loading a new texture.In mobile its very much a game changer of what you can pull off when you use proper memory mapping. and the worst part of not using VBOs is your just coping memory from one space to another every frame ever time you load a texture. When changing VBO id your just changing the pointer(4 bytes) where the stored data is on the video/opengl memory. how much memory exchange is going on one 2048x2048 texture: 4.1k per texture that is read every time you change. 4194304 bytes - 4 bytes = 4194304 bytes save a frame!

Comment: If your drawing 100's textures in your frame: 1of2 things is true:1. they are all really small textures 1-20px wide&tall. or 2.they are all(mostly) transparent.  If one of these is not true then you are wasting resources on doing work that is never seen by drawing everything. You need to have lazy-loading for you pixel data on a back-thread. I would not worry about how many times your switch states (that's a topic when you want to do complex lighting & reflections) but loading a texture is not something you want to do between start draw frame and end draw frame. this is where opengl shines.

Comment: Other thing you can try is glEnable:GL_DEPTH_TEST and z-value, lower z is father a way. Also it seems some people think that just because they don't update the vertex data every frame they just don't need to update vertext/texture data and making drawing calls every frame is ok and it's not true. If you don't update anything, nothings moved or animated then just don't do anything to the scene and don't rebind-clear your framebuffers. iOS will just redisplay the same pixels 60fps. Add two bools to your objects, dirty & offScreen. dirty=update,offScreen=dont Draw. It's worth keeping track.

Comment: "What if I have hundreeds of such mixed sprites?" So what if you do? Do you have *evidence* that this will be a significant performance problem?

Comment: Nicol are you asking if not using buffered objects and having hundreds of textures will lead to performance issues?  Or just havin having hundreds of textures alone will even if your using buffers on the gpu?

Comment: @NicolBolas I'm having performance issues, barely can make 60 fps on iphone 4S. I'm pretty sure it's because I'm using dynamic branching in fragment shader that kills all parallelism. I see this in apple GL debugger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have evidence of a real performance issue (and you shouldn't bother with this unless you do), the solution is quite easy: use your depth buffer.

Use an orthographic projection so that sprites don't get bigger/smaller when they move forward. Give each sprite a depth value, and let the depth test remove unwanted parts of sprites.

Comment: Oh I didn't see your answer here, but if your building a framework how can know what will the end user of your API is going to throw at it? Why would you not build for the worst case? If your just one use case in mind then just sure just stress that make it work commit the code and move on.

Comment: I thought about this ... But will this break pixel perfect texture matching because of z value? What if I'm rendering multiple VBO's those I sent first will be already in color buffer?